# Remove() method for a doubly linked list

Tags: java, list, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

```
 /**
 * The remove() method removes the current node from the list. If the next node exists,
 * it becomes the current node. Otherwise the previous node becomes the current node. 
 * If neither node exists, the list becomes empty.
 * 
 * @throws Exception    If the list is empty.
 */

public void remove() throws Exception
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw exListEmpty;
    }
    Node target = current;      
    Node prevNode = target.prev;
    Node nextNode = target.next;

    // current node is at head
    if (prevNode == null)
    {
        nextNode.prev = null;
        head = nextNode;
    }
    else
    {
        prevNode.next = nextNode;
        current = prevNode;
    }

    // current node is at tail
    if (nextNode == null)
    {
        prevNode.next = null;
        tail = prevNode;
    }
    else
    {
        nextNode.prev = prevNode;
        current = nextNode;
    }
    if (prevNode == null && nextNode == null)
    {
        isEmpty();
    }
    else if (prevNode != null && nextNode != null)
    {
        prevNode.next = nextNode;
        nextNode.prev = prevNode;
        current = nextNode;
    }
    size--; 
}
```

The test code is:

```
    public void testContains() throws Exception
    {
        PDLinkedList first = new PDLinkedList();
        first.append(5);
        first.insert(7);
        first.add(8);

        System.out.println("Before first remove: " + first.toString());
        first.remove(); 
        System.out.println("After first remove: " + first.toString());
        first.remove(5);
        System.out.println("After second remove: " + first.toString());
        first.remove();
        System.out.println("After third remove: " + first.toString());
    }
```

Which then prints out as:

```
Before first remove: 7 8 5
After first remove: 7 8 5
After second remove: 7 8
After third remove: 7 8
```

It should remove the 8 after the first remove(), then the 7 after the third remove(). My add(item) method is set as the current pointer, and my remove() method should then remove the node at the current pointer. But it seems to do nothing. I wonder if it is pointing at the wrong node? The code compiles, but I receive an Assertion Error that states the 7 and 8 are still in the list.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 4):

Consider removing a node in 5 distinct cases:

1. List is empty
2. List contains only one element
3. Target node is in the beginning
4. Target node is in the end
5. Target node is at other position

Do no mash everything in one long function, break it into corresponding steps:

(1) Is easy, just return

(2) You make both `head` and `last` point to `null`

(3) You assign `head` to `head.next`, and `head.previous` to `null` (`head` is already "new" head)

```
void RemoveAtStart()
{
    if (IsEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }

    if (Head == Last)
    {
        Head = null;
        Last = null;
    }
    else
    {
        Head = Head.Next;
        Head.Previous = null;
    }       
}
```

(4) Is very similar: `last` becomes `last.previous`, and `last.next` to `null` (`last` is "new" last)

```
void RemoveAtEnd()
{
    if (IsEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }

    if (Last == Head)
    {
        Last = null;
        Head = null;            
    }
    else
    {
        Last = Last.Previous;
        Last.Next = null;
    }       
}
```

(5) You find `target`, then point `target.previous.next` to `target.next` ("left" node of target skips it, and points to the right node of target). Then, if target is not the last, point `target.Next.Previous` to `target.Previous`.

Then you combine all cases `1-5`:

```
void Remove(Node<T> node)
{
    if (IsEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }

    if (Head == Last)
    {
        Head = null;
        Last = null;
    }
    else if (node == Last)
    {
        RemoveAtEnd();
    }
    else if (node == Head)
    {
        RemoveAtStart();
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T> current = Head;
        while (current != node)
        {
            current = current.Next;
        }
        current.Previous.Next = current.Next;
        if (current.Next != null)
        {
            current.Next.Previous = current.Previous;
        }        
        current = null;        
    }       
}
```

Comment: I'm sort of working on something similar, except I have an index in my parameter. Do you think you can help me out? I wrote a question out, but no one has been answering and I've been digging through my book and internet, but no results.